# How to change the column names in all my data frames inside a list?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list with several data frames, each with the same structure, and I want to change the column name of all the data frames.

I have tried both using rename options from the `dplyr` package and use map to apply it to every data frame in the list.

Here's some code:

```
#Generating some data to exemplify the situation
   foo = list(testA = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol = 5)),
              testB = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol = 5)),
              testC = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol = 5)))

#New name for data frame columns
   newNames = c('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May')

# Packages
   library(dplyr)
   library(purrr)
```

First, I tried using `rename_all` from `dplyr` hoping the command would automatically match every column with a name (from first to last) from my `newNames` vector, but this did not work

```
foo <- foo %>% rename_all(meses)
```

Then I tried creating a simple function called `renameColumn`:

```
renameColumn = function(myData, new_names){
  colnames(data) = new_names
}
```

and using the function inside `map`. This approach also didn't work.

```
map(.x = foo, 
    .f = renameColumn(myData = foo, new_names = newNames))
```

How to achieve the end goal of naming all data frame columns with the `newNames` vector using, preferably, `dplyr` and `map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier option is `set_names` if we are changing the names of all the columns

```
foo1 <- map(foo, set_names, newNames)
foo1
#$testA
#         Jan        Feb           Mar        Apr       May
#1 -0.2886904  0.7716465  0.7103408795 -0.3209754 0.1580680
#2  0.8776646  0.1441515  1.9820892400 -2.5664872 0.2014593
#3 -1.9172889  1.4930354 -0.0005122859  2.7473145 0.9806701
#4 -0.7642281 -1.7382739  2.8574676114  0.1905533 1.0760523
#5 -0.2753768  0.4712059 -0.8955168101 -0.3923635 1.1017868

#$testB
#         Jan        Feb          Mar        Apr       May
#1 -1.2544946 -0.2131777  0.634624485  1.5436530 0.5811060
#2 -0.8092116  1.6085164  2.607820897  0.5454936 1.3869741
#3 -0.5460344  0.8028537 -0.007151318 -0.1711816 0.0867885
#4 -0.2104260 -1.3580934  0.835981664  1.3725253 0.0037494
#5 -0.6984177  1.2311613 -0.809374023 -0.2487121 0.8129935

#$testC
#         Jan         Feb        Mar         Apr         May
#1  0.3667708 -0.01209575 -0.9314844  0.05995604  0.58699473
#2  1.4171330  0.62793554 -0.2695517  2.21667643  0.90599396
#3  1.7093434 -0.98627309 -1.7552439 -0.96652771 -0.05704485
#4  0.2860338  1.34541312 -1.9608085 -1.23959279  0.19175618
#5 -0.9364102  2.47658828 -1.4883768  0.64809561 -0.99417796
```

---

or if we use `rename_all`, make sure to use the `~`.  According to `?rename_all`, the `.funs` argument would be

> .funs - A function fun, a purrr style lambda ~ fun(.) or a list of either form.

```
foo2 <- map(foo, ~ .x %>%
               rename_all(~ newNames))

identical(foo1, foo2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

In the function `renameColumn`, there are two issues - 1) nothing is `return`ed.  2) argument mismatch - function argument (`myData`) is different from the one used inside (`data`)

```
renameColumn = function(myData, new_names){
     colnames(myData) <- new_names
     myData
 }

map(foo, renameColumn, new_names = newNames)
```